# Android database table data to specific model object

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin

I have sqlite database with table 'data' as

uid    type   name    value
1       abc   North    10
1       abc   South    0
1       abc   East     0
1       abc   West     0
1       abc   Total    10
1       xyz   Total    20
1       xyz   Open     10
1       xyz   Close    10

Using select query I am able to get this table data, now I need to create response object having following structure

DataModel(String type, Arraylist<Data> data)
Data(String name, String value)

expected output json will be
{"data":[{"type":"abc", "values":[{"name":"North", "value":"10"}, {"name":"South", "value":"0"}...]},
{"type":"xyz", "values":[{"name":"total", "value":"20"}, {"name":"open", "value":"10"}...]}]}

for now I tried this kotlin code in android studio & its working well 'result' Arraylist contains above table data

```
                val dataList: ArrayList<DashboardDataModel> = ArrayList()
                val typeAyyList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

                for(res in result){
                    typeAyyList.add(res.type)
                }

                val distinct = typeAyyList.toSet().toList()

                for(type in distinct) {
                    val values: ArrayList<DashboardData> = ArrayList()

                    for (res in result) {
                        if (type == res.type) {
                            val dash=DashboardData()
                            dash.name=res.name
                            dash.value=res.value
                            values.add(dash)
                        }
                    }

                    val data = DashboardDataModel()
                    data.type=type
                    data.values=values
                    dataList.add(data)
                }
```

Is there any better solution available?

Any help/suggestion please?

Comment: Can you show me what you've tried ?

Comment: @MD Hi, please find updated question